# Foundation.min.js in error line

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, zurb-foundation

I've a syntax error on this line of my code of fondation.min.js but I don't find where is the error?
Anyone have an idea?

```
(n):t.position_content(n,!1)})},is_vertical_nav:function(e){return/vertical-nav/i.test(e.data("section"))},is_horizontal_nav:function(e){return/horizontal-nav/i.test(e.data("section"))},is_accordion:function(e){return/accordion/i.test(e.data("section"))},is_horizontal_tabs:function(e){return/^tabs$/i.test(e.data("section"))},is_vertical_tabs:function(e){return/vertical-tabs/i.test(e.data("section"))},set_active_from_hash:function(){var n=t.location.hash.substring(1),r=e("[data-section]"),i=this;r.each(function(){var t=e(this),r=e.extend({},i.settings,i.data_options(t));if(n.length>0&&r.deep_linking){var s=t.children(i.settings.region_selector).attr("style","").removeClass("active"),o=s.map(function(){var t=e(i.settings.content_selector,this),r=t.data("slug");if((new RegExp(r,"i")).test(n))return t}),u=o.length;for(var a=u-1;a>=0;a--)e(o[a]).parent().addClass("active")}})},position_titles:function(t,n){var r=this,i=t.children(this.settings.region_selector).map(function(){return e(this).children(r.settings.title_selector)}),s=0,o=0,r=this;typeof n=="boolean"?i.attr("style",""):i.each(function(){r.is_vertical_tabs(t)?(e(this).css("top",o),o+=r.outerHeight(e(this))):(r.rtl?e(this).css("right",s):e(this).css("left",s),s+=r.outerWidth(e(this)))})},position_content:function(t,n){var r=this,i=t.children(r.settings.region_selector),s=i.map(function(){return e(this).children(r.settings.title_selector)}),o=i.map(function(){return e(this).children(r.settings.content_selector)});if(typeof n=="boolean")o.attr("style",""),t.attr("style","");else if(r.is_vertical_tabs(t)&&!r.small(t)){var u=0,a=Number.MAX_VALUE,f=null;i.each(function(){var n=e(this),i=n.children(r.settings.title_selector),s=n.children(r.settings.content_selector),o=0;f=r.outerWidth(i),o=r.outerWidth(t)-f,o<a&&(a=o),u+=r.outerHeight(i),e(this).hasClass("active")||s.css("display","none")}),i.each(function(){var t=e(this).children(r.settings.content_selector);t.css("minHeight",u),t.css("maxWidth",a-2)})}else i.each(function(){var t=e(this),n=t.children(r.settings.title_selector),i=t.children(r.settings.content_selector);r.rtl?i.css({right:r.position_right(n)+1,top:r.outerHeight(n)-2}):i.css({left:n.position().left-1,top:r.outerHeight(n)-2})}),typeof Zepto=="function"?t.height(this.outerHeight(e(s[0]))):t.height(this.outerHeight(e(s[0]))-2)},position_right:function(t){var n=this,r=t.closest(this.settings.section_selector),i=r.children(this.settings.region_selector),s=t.closest(this.settings.section_selector).width(),o=i.map(function(){return e(this).children(n.settings.title_selector)}).length;return s-t.position().left-t.width()*(t.index()+1)-o},reflow:function(t){var t=t||n;e(this.settings.section_selector,t).trigger("resize")},small:function(t){var n=e.extend({},this.settings,this.data_options(t));return this.is_horizontal_tabs(t)?!1:t&&this.is_accordion(t)?!0:e("html").hasClass("lt-ie9")?!0:e("html").hasClass("ie8compat")?!0:e(this.scope).width()<768},off:function(){e(this.scope).off(".fndtn.section"),e(t).off(".fndtn.section"),e(n).off(".fndtn.section")}}}(Foundation.zj,this,this.document),function(e,t,n,r){"use strict";Foundation.libs.topbar={name:"topbar",version:"4.2.0",settings:{index:0,stickyClass:"sticky",custom_back_text:!0,back_text:"Back",is_hover:!0,scrolltop:!0,init:!1},init:function(n,r,i){Foundation.inherit(this,"data_options");var s=this;return typeof r=="object"?e.extend(!0,this.settings,r):typeof i!="undefined"&&e.extend(!0,this.settings,i),typeof r!="string"?(e(".top-bar, [data-topbar]").each(function(){e.extend(!0,s.settings,s.data_options(e(this))),s.settings.$w=e(t),s.settings.$topbar=e(this),s.settings.$section=s.settings.$topbar.find("section"),s.settings.$titlebar=s.settings.$topbar.children("ul").first(),s.settings.$topbar.data("index",0);var n=e("<div class='top-bar-js-breakpoint'/>").insertAfter(s.settings.$topbar);s.settings.breakPoint=n.width(),n.remove(),s.assemble(),s.settings.$topbar.parent().hasClass("fixed")&&e("body").css("padding-top",s.outerHeight(s.settings.$topbar))}),s.settings.init||this.events(),this.settings.init):this[r].call(this,i)},events:function(){var n=this,r=this.outerHeight(e(".top-bar, [data-topbar]"));e(this.scope).off(".fndtn.topbar").on("click.fndtn.topbar",".top-bar .toggle-topbar, [data-topbar] .toggle-topbar",function(i){var s=e(this).closest(".top-bar, [data-topbar]"),o=s.find("section, .section"),u=s.children("ul").first();i.preventDefault(),n.breakpoint()&&(n.rtl?(o.css({right:"0%"}),o.find(">.name").css({right:"100%"})):(o.css({left:"0%"}),o.find(">.name").css({left:"100%"})),o.find("li.moved").removeClass("moved"),s.data("index",0),s.toggleClass("expanded").css("min-height","")),s.hasClass("expanded")?s.parent().hasClass("fixed")&&(s.parent().removeClass("fixed"),s.addClass("fixed"),e("body").css("padding-top","0"),n.settings.scrolltop&&t.scrollTo(0,0)):s.hasClass("fixed")&&(s.parent().addClass("fixed"),s.removeClass("fixed"),e("body").css("padding-top",r))}).on("mouseenter mouseleave",".top-bar li",function(t){if(!n.settings.is_hover)return;/enter|over/i.test(t.type)?e(this).addClass("hover"):e(this).removeClass("hover")}).on("click.fndtn.topbar",".top-bar li.has-dropdown",function(t){if(n.breakpoint())return;var r=e(this),i=e(t.target),s=r.closest("[data-topbar], .top-bar"),o=s.data("topbar");if(n.settings.is_hover&&!Modernizr.touch)return;t.stopImmediatePropagation(),i[0].nodeName==="A"&&i.parent().hasClass("has-dropdown")&&t.preventDefault(),r.hasClass("hover")?r.removeClass("hover").find("li").removeClass("hover"):r.addClass("hover")}).on("click.fndtn.topbar",".top-bar .has-dropdown>a, [data-topbar] .has-dropdown>a",function(t){if(n.breakpoint()){t.preventDefault();var r=e(this),i=r.closest(".top-bar, [data-topbar]"),s=i.find("section, .section"),o=i.children("ul").first(),u=r.next(".dropdown").outerHeight(),a=r.closest("li");i.data("index",i.data("index")+1),a.addClass("moved"),n.rtl?(s.css({right:-(100*i.data("index"))+"%"}),s.find(">.name").css({right:100*i.data("index")+"%"})):(s.css({left:-(100*i.data("index"))+"%"}),s.find(">.name").css({left:100*i.data("index")+"%"})),i.css("min-height",n.height(r.siblings("ul"))+n.outerHeight(o,!0))}}),e(t).on("resize.fndtn.topbar",function(){n.breakpoint()||e(".top-bar, [data-topbar]").css("min-height","").removeClass("expanded").find("li").removeClass("hover")}.bind(this)),e("body").on("click.fndtn.topbar",function(t){var n=e(t.target).closest("[data-topbar], .top-bar");if(n.length>0)return;e(".top-bar li, [data-topbar] li").removeClass("hover")}),e(this.scope).on("click.fndtn",".top-bar .has-dropdown .back, [data-topbar] .has-dropdown .back",function(t){t.preventDefault();var r=e(this),i=r.closest(".top-bar, [data-topbar]"),s=i.children("ul").first(),o=i.find("section, .section"),u=r.closest("li.moved"),a=u.parent();i.data("index",i.data("index")-1),n.rtl?(o.css({right:-(100*i.data("index"))+"%"}),o.find(">.name").css({right:100*i.data("index")+"%"})):(o.css({left:-(100*i.data("index"))+"%"}),o.find(">.name").css({left:100*i.data("index")+"%"})),i.data("index")===0?i.css("min-height",0):i.css("min-height",n.height(a)+n.outerHeight(s,!0)),setTimeout(function(){u.removeClass("moved")},300)})},breakpoint:function(){return e(t).width()<=this.settings.breakPoint||e("html").hasClass("lt-ie9")},assemble:function(){var t=this;this.settings.$section.detach(),this.settings.$section.find(".has-dropdown>a").each(function(){var n=e(this),r=n.siblings(".dropdown"),i=n.attr("href");if(i&&i.length>1)var s=e('<li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="#"></a></h5></li><li><a class="parent-link js-generated" href="'+i+'">'+n.text()+"</a></li>");else var s=e('<li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="#"></a></h5></li>');t.settings.custom_back_text==1?s.find("h5>a").html("&laquo; "+t.settings.back_text):s.find("h5>a").html("&laquo; "+n.html()),r.prepend(s)}),this.settings.$section.appendTo(this.settings.$topbar),this.sticky()},height:function(t){var n=0,r=this;return t.find("> li").each(function(){n+=r.outerHeight(e(this),!0)}),n},sticky:function(){var n="."+this.settings.stickyClass;if(e(n).length>0){var r=e(n).length?e(n).offset().top:0,i=e(t),s=this.outerHeight(e(".top-bar"));i.scroll(function(){i.scrollTop()>=r?(e(n).addClass("fixed"),e("body").css("padding-top",s)):i.scrollTop()<r&&(e(n).removeClass("fixed"),e("body").css("padding-top","0"))})}},off:function(){e(this.scope).off(".fndtn.topbar"),e(t).off(".fndtn.topbar")},reflow:function(){}}}(Foundation.zj,this,this.document);
```

Comment: You'll find the error isn't with `foundation.min.js` but with something in your code that has called `foundation` At least normally ;) Also adding the entire plugin will not help anybody debug anything.

Comment: The error is in foundation.min.js because I've modify it for my website but I don't find my copies with no errors :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use Foundation.js to work, and when you fix the error you use the min version ?
And the problem will be in how you implement, not in the foundation js(probably)

Comment: I've put the original foundation.min.js and it work perfectly with no errors :D